# Bond two queries

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

```
SELECT MAX(SerNo) FROM [DeviceList] 

SELECT substring (SerNo) FROM [DeviceList]
```

There are two queries:

- the first query gets max number in the column
- the second one is split first 3 characters from that selected number

The number is like "SE001", "SE002".

My requirement is to get max number and split first two string from it (the result is 001 only). I need a single query to do this - please help me.

Comment: In your example, the max number would be `'002'`, not `'001`, so I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just combine `MAX()` and `SUBSTRING()` together

```
SELECT SUBSTRING ( MAX( SerNo ), 3, 3 )
FROM   [DeviceList]
```

Comment: @Squirrel . . . I would be inclined to use `RIGHT()` instead of `SUBSTRING()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT RIGHT(SerNo, 3) FROM (SELECT MAX(SerNo) [Serno] FROM [DeviceList])
```

Should do the trick, even though a little more info would be appreciated